# Pragmatic Way to Store String Formats

Tags: java, formatting

Suppose I have a protocol that accepts a string in the form:

```
static final String PROTOCOL_FORMAT = "%s%sT%s%sT%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s";
```

Where every `%s` refers to some piece of data that must substituted into the format in order to complete the message.

Personally, I find storing the format in this sort of string substitution to be quite hard to read. Is there any standard way to handle stuff like this? How could I make this more expressive? The only thing I can think of is abstracting the `PROTOCOL_FORMAT` out to its own class.

Edit (Example of usage):

```
String.format("%s%sT%s%sT%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s",
              data1,data2,data3...);
```

Where every every piece data{n} could contain different information from every other piece.

```
Output:12T12T1234567890
```

However, that last `0` could easily be `99999999` - or any string of any length.

Comment: "The only thing I can think of is abstracting the PROTOCOL_FORMAT out to its own class." And it annoys you ? It seems a good idea to provide a specific class that could provide method to build the String. In your case (many parts to value), a fluent API seems also appropriate.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily annoy me, I was just more interested in seeing if other people handled similar situations differently.

Comment: I understand your point. You may implement it in multiple ways indeed but you have finally two main ways to do it : introducing abstraction for your requirement (with many ways to do it) or not introducing it (with less ways to do it)

Comment: It depends on how you're processing the format. Are all the `%s` strings are to be replaced with the same data thus becoming something like `aaTaaTaaa...` or is each occurrence replaced based on the index of the occurrence or whether you're using RegEx. Please add more information, an example would help.

Comment: I updated the question. All components of the string can be anything. For example, the first two might be `0,1`, whereas the last one could be `99999999`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a pragmatic way to go about building the message format. In this case, it's best to use a builder class to construct the message on the fly. The `MESSAGE_FORMAT` is stored in the builder.

What I did was create a `MessageBuilder` class that has methods which slowly fill in the required data. For those unfamiliar, this is the `builder` design pattern.

For example:

```
String message = MessageBuilder()
    .displayValue(123)
    .lightColorOne(RED)
    .lightColorTwo(GREEN)
    .lightColorThree(BLUE)
    .build();
```

`message >> "12T12T1234567890"`